# Adding a dimension to a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to add a new matrix to a previously existant matrix, but on his dimension coordinate.
I know this is hard to understand, so let's see it on a example:

I've a matrix like this:

```
480x640x3
```

And I want to add the following one:

```
480x640x6
```

The result has be this: (6+3 = 9)

```
480x640x9
```

As you can see it adds but on the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For concatenating along higher dimensions, use the function [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html):

```
newMatrix = cat(3,matrix1,matrix2);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would say that gnovice's answer is probably the best way to go, but you could do it this way too:

```
matrix1(:,:,4:9) = matrix2;
```

Comment: Good answer. The only drawback is that you'd have to know/get the sizes of the third dimension for each matrix beforehand.